# Create and plot control limits in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have made predictions using the ML model and trying to plot the actual vs the predicted values on a scatter plot. X axis is actual value and Y axis is predicted value.
Red dots in the image below are the (actual,predicted)  coordinate and the black is the ideal (actual,actual) coordinate.

[image]

I want to map the lines with +-20% variation in the actual in the same graph. Something like below image.

[image]

I am trying with the following code:

```
ggplot(data=pred_data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=predicted_value),color="red",size=1.5)+
  geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value),color="black",size=0.5)+
  geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value*0.8),color="black")+
  geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value*1.2),color="black")+
  ylab("Predicted")+
  xlab("Actual")+
  ggtitle("Actual, Random Forest Model")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=18),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12))
```

But its not working out. This may create some graph for specific case, but when data changes, the line are way too wide or narrow and not parallel

Answer (score 0):

If you want parallel lines, you should be adding and subtracting from actual_value, not multiplying.

If you want something that is usable no matter the data, you can either normalize the data and always add/remove a fixed value, or add/remove some transformation of the standard deviation of your variable. 
For example:

```
ggplot(data=pred_data)+
geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=predicted_value),color="red",size=1.5)+
geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value),color="black",size=0.5)+
geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value+sd(actual_value)),color="black")+
geom_point(aes(x=actual_value,y=actual_value-sd(actual_value)),color="black")+
ylab("Predicted")+
xlab("Actual")+
ggtitle("Actual, Random Forest Model")+
theme(axis.title = element_text(size=18),
    plot.title = element_text(size=20),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12))
```

EDIT: in particular, the +- 20% is not really clear to me. Maybe you can add/remove the 20% of your max value, like:

```
y=actual_value + 0.2*max(actual_value)
```